# Cannot connect to AWS IoT service, MqttException - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, client-certificates, aws-iot

I am trying to establish a connection between my device and the AWS IoT service using TLS 1.2 authentication via MQTT Client. As per the AWS IoT documentation, I stored the RootCA certificate inside JAVA_Home/jre/Lib/Security/CACerts in a keystore. I was able to generate the certificate and keys for the device to be used to connect to AWS IoT service using CreateKeysAndCertificateResult. Later, I created X.509 certificate from PEM string and the RsaCrtKeySpec object from the private key string in the keypair object. I saved this in a keystore and used the keystore in the MQTT Client object to connect to AWS IoT. However, the connect() throws an exception listed below. Any help on this will be appreciated.

```
Aug 11, 2017 10:49:18 AM 
com.amazonaws.services.iot.client.mqtt.AwsIotMqttConnectionListener 
onFailure
WARNING: Connect request failure
MqttException (0) - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal 
alert: certificate_unknown
```

Answer (score 0):

Try ensuring your certificate is active in the IOT console. Under `certificates` > `actions` >`activate`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giYVg.png)

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you have missed to point out?

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=yourtruststore 
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password
```